# I want to Display Square Checkbox on IOS ,IPad in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

```
This Below is my IOS Page .I want to show this type of check box on iOS in xamarin form. I have use Xamarin 5.0 version. When I am try to use check element in iOS show rounded check box but I want square check box.

 <CheckBox  x:Name="chkRememberMe"  BackgroundColor="#7E7E7E" SizeChanged="20" IsChecked="False" CheckedChanged="ChkRememberMe_OnCheckedChanged" ></CheckBox>
```

This is my check box code what can I do that in iOS for a square checkbox.I'm completely new to xamarin.forms, I need to add a checkbox, radio buttons and drop down list. I tried some samples from net but I'm not able to get the checkbox. Can anyone help me to achieve.Controls.Checkbox to create checkbox for ios and andorid in Xamarin Forms.Now i am getting the checkbox but i cant read the value either it is checked or not.Here is my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the plugin **[Xamarin.Forms.InputKit](https://github.com/enisn/Xamarin.Forms.InputKit)** from nuget .

```
xmlns:input="clr-namespace:Plugin.InputKit.Shared.Controls;assembly=Plugin.InputKit"
```

```
 <input:CheckBox Text="xxx" Type="Check"/>
```

If you want to customize the style of the checkbox ,  you could check https://github.com/enisn/Xamarin.Forms.InputKit/wiki/CheckBox .

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the check boxes on other platforms, you can use a custom renderer to only change how it looks on iOS.

Subclass the `CheckBox` in your shared project:
`public class CustomCheckBox : CheckBox  {}`

And add the custom renderer to the iOS project:

```
using CoreGraphics;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using YourApp.iOS;
using YourApp.Controls; // namespace of your CustomCheckBox
using System.ComponentModel;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomCheckBox), typeof(CustomCheckBoxRenderer))]
namespace YourApp.iOS
{
    public class CustomCheckBoxRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomCheckBox, UIView>
    {
        private const float SideLength = 18f;
        private bool firstTime = true;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomCheckBox> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
            {
                var checkBox = new UIView();
                SetNativeControl(checkBox);
            }
        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (e.PropertyName == CustomCheckBox.IsCheckedProperty.PropertyName || firstTime)
            {
                SetNeedsDisplay();
            }
        }

        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            Element.Color.ToUIColor().SetStroke();
            if (Element.IsChecked)
            {
                var checkPath = new UIBezierPath();
                checkPath.MoveTo(new CGPoint(1 + .2 * SideLength, 1 + .475 * SideLength));
                checkPath.AddLineTo(new CGPoint(1 + .45 * SideLength, 1 + .675 * SideLength));
                checkPath.AddLineTo(new CGPoint(1 + .8 * SideLength, 1 + .275 * SideLength));
                checkPath.LineWidth = 3f;
                checkPath.Stroke();
            }

            var boxPath = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(
                new CGRect(1f, 1f, SideLength, SideLength), UIRectCorner.AllCorners, new CGSize(2,2));
            boxPath.LineWidth = 2f;
            boxPath.Stroke();
            firstTime = false;
        }

        public override CGSize SizeThatFits(CGSize size)
        {
            return new CGSize(SideLength + 2, SideLength + 2);
        }
    }
}
```